# WebSite Loading Issue In Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, loading, smoothing, web-content

i have created a website.

its admin panel is same like [Admin Panel Link](http://preview.themebucket.net/?item=bucketadmin)

The problem is when i click on each link in
Firefox : it loads all contents smoothly.but in
Chrome  : Some camera flash type effect occur on click of Link 
So, whats solution of to remove that camera flash type effect in Chrome.

(i don't want to use Loader for Content Load)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243105/google-chrome-override-white-blank-page-between-webpage-loads)

Comment: @Celt - that question is give solution to change color of it.. but i want to remove that white flash effect.

Comment: I know but have you looked at other questions? There are a number related to this problem, it has been around for a while.

Comment: yes.. i looked for all. if you faced this issue then tell me how to solve it ..