# How to Dim Chrome loading screen between page loads (to black out white flash)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, html, high-contrast

As a dimming/darkening work around to the [notorious white flash in between Chrome page loads](https://superuser.com/questions/717343/how-can-i-make-chromes-white-flash-when-a-new-tab-is-opened-be-black?lq=1), how could the small default loading notification (below) be exploited to cover the entire screen?

In other words, is it possible to create an entire *wall of text* in between page loads such that a [high contrast extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/care-your-eyes/fidmpnedniahpnkeomejhnepmbdamlhl?hl=en) could then darken the entire screen just as it darkens a small portion here?:
[image]

This is quite hacky, but for good reason. All other solutions no longer work for Chrome 40+:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/580228/prevent-white-screen-before-loading-page-in-chromium
2. [Google Chrome - Override White Blank page between webpage loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243105/google-chrome-override-white-blank-page-between-webpage-loads)
3. https://superuser.com/questions/831742/how-do-you-change-chromes-background-color

Comment: If I get understand correctly, you want to dim lights till the page is loaded ?

Comment: correct - I want to replace the white loading screen with a black one. As previously reported solutions no longer work, this is my creative attempt at a work around. I've clarified my question - thanks

Comment: another hack by forking the source code here https://github.com/hbtlabs/chromium-white-flash-fix

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to change what that status bar shows, not without digging into Chromium's source (but then you could just change how `about:blank` looks).

The idea is indeed way too hacky.

Comment: how would you change how `about:blank` looks? The overall objective is to get rid of the white flashed screen before the next page loads, so if you know an ends to that means please do share.

Comment: Your question is specifically about that status bar. You, yourself, showed that there are questions on this topic already - either edit them to bump them to the top, or better yet offer a bounty.