# Google Chrome - Override White Blank page when loading new tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

"I'm looking for different Chrome apps to make my pages darker/inverted to reduce eye strain, I found some apps that work but the only thing left, which these apps doesn't seem to override, is the White Blank page.

When a new page is loaded, Chrome first displays a White Blank page, while the page is loading then displays the website's content. Is there a way to override this While page to say Black? At the moment, everytime I click on a link or open a new webpage, the screen goes from darkcoloured (through inverted/darkening page apps) to the White Blank screen for a brief second then the new page loads in a dark colour again. This acts like a "White Flash" by the screen everytime a new page is loaded and causes further eye strain. This is why I want to know if there is a way to override this White colour to Black."

This question was already asked before in here, but the answers suggested back then do not seem to be working on my current version of chrome 49.0.2623.87 m.

The links that I have referred to already :

-[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243105/google-chrome-override-white-blank-page-between-webpage-loads)

-comment 261 [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373)

-[This](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OhHr9gqj06k)

I created two files manifest.json and script.js in AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\

and did the "load unpacked extension" and that did not work either.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit 2021-01-01**

Install **chromium-based** [Brave](https://brave.com/) web browser as a drop-in alternative to Chrome. Then:

- Install [DarkReader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh)
- Click `Settings` > `Appearance` > `Brave colors` > `Dark`
- Open new tab and click `Customize` in new tab page to get an *acceptably* dark appearance:
  [image]

Additional Benefits to Brave:

Brave is forked off of chromium, so generally behaves the same as chrome. It prioritizes user privacy and comes built-in with Ad Blocking capability that is also very easy to disable as you're browsing. Plus many other features I'm not mentioning here.

**Original Solution (If you really don't want to use Brave)**

As of April 2016, this issue has been pending for over 8 years (aside from the intermittent work-arounds that no longer apply as you pointed out). If you haven't already, please consider "starring" these reported issues.

***Current Reported Bugs:***

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470669
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457714
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128290
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119871
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409378
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=126341
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64317
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530026

Especially the first two links appear to be gaining some traction. More users that support them being fixed helps gain more attention and allows you to monitor progress from email notifications (or you can unsubscribe).

***Report This Issue:***

Next, submit feedback to chrome through your browser following these steps:

1. Open Chrome and click the "hamburger" menu on the top right corner
2. Click Help > Report an issue.
3. Add detail similar to the following:

> Between page loads and new tabs being opened, there is a brief moment
> where the entire browser screen is painted white, causing severe eye
> strain.
>
> This issue has been referred to in the following chromium issues:
>
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470669
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457714
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128290
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119871
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409378
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=126341
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64317
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530026

4. Click send feedback

I would then recommend installing [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html), as some of the experimental fixes to those issues above will first appear in Canary.

***Invert Computer Colors:***

Finally, as a last resort, turn on color inversion and use the whitest chrome theme possible.

- http://smallbusiness.chron.com/invert-colors-computer-43975.html
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5780779?start=0

White theme (that is very dark when inverted):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimal-white/clcbojcafbggjenbeflknhfimpcikmlc?hl=en-GB

Comment: I submitted feedback accordingly; thanks for templating that out. This was never an issue for me until I started suffering from migraines a couple of years ago. That white flash absolutely demolishes my head and eyes, so I have to wear sunglasses -- all because of that one initial paint problem. It's unbelievable to me that they haven't at least allowed themes to modify that as well. Seems like a no-brainer in an age of dark mode being so prevalent. That said, I've noticed this issue with other apps, like Twitter mobile. Even in dark mode, the app first loads with a bright-white screen. Dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Significantly better in Chrome-Beta and even better in Chrome-Dev (chrome-unstable), almost unnoticeable.
Using Ubuntu-Cinnamon-Remix 21.04.